# How to upload encoded metadata to sharepoint using ValidateUpdateListItem method?

Tags: java, rest, sharepoint

I am trying to upload metadata to SharePoint server using ValidateUpdateListItem method. In this method, value of bNewDocumentUpdate is true to avoid creating a new version for the uploaded file. The name of metadata which has to be updated, is 'cc1'. When i fetch metadata information, the name of metadata is converted from 'cc1' to 'OData__x0063_c1'. Now, i have used both the names (encoded and decoded) to upload the metadata, but below error is generated -

```
{"error":{"code":"-2147024809, System.ArgumentException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Column 'cc1' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.  /Shared Documents"}}}
```

Earlier, i was not using ValidateUpdateListItem method, and was able to upload metadata using encoded name.
Is there any way to upload the encoded metadata while using ValidateUpdateListItem method?

Comment: can you share the code you are using ?

Comment: metaDataList = getMetadataList(extractedValueMap, metadataMappingList);   
   if(null != metaDataList) {
    formValuesMap = new JsonObject();
    formValuesMap.add("formValues",metaDataList);
    formValuesMap.addProperty("bNewDocumentUpdate", true);
   }

Comment: innerMetadata.addProperty("type", "SP.ListItemFormUpdateValue");   
   for (SPMetadataMapping spMetadataMapping : metadataMappingList) {
    String fieldName = spMetadataMapping.getFieldType().getName();
    if (extractedValueMap.containsKey(fieldName)) {
     metadataMap = new JsonObject();
     metadataMap.addProperty("FieldName", SPMetadataDecoderUtil.decodeMetadataTitle(spMetadataMapping.getMetadataName()));
     metadataMap.addProperty("FieldValue", extractedValueMap.get(fieldName));
     metadataMap.add("__metadata", innerMetadata);   
    metaDataList.add(metadataMap);    
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Update -

This problem has been resolved by using 'InternalName' of metadata. Earlier i was using 'EntityPropertyName' of metadata to set metadata value.